# value is missing query values to be interpolated properly event provide in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I go to url `http://local:3000/customize/collection/doremon1234a/schema/dfs/template/50`

[image]

Enven I provide [colName - doremon1234a], [schemaName - dfs], [templateId - 50] But it still gets errors

I try to remove .next folder, and clone source code again. But it does not work
Anyone gets the same issue like me.
Thanks
THis is my folder structure
[image]

my source code

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { serverSideTranslations } from "next-i18next/serverSideTranslations";
import { useTranslation } from "next-i18next";
import { i18n } from "@/config";

function TemplateId() {
const { t } = useTranslation("common");
const router = useRouter();
const { colName, schemaName,  templateId } = router.query;

return (
    <>
        <div>{templateId}</div>
    </>
);
}

export async function getServerSideProps({ locale }) {
try {
    const translations = await serverSideTranslations(locale, ["common"], {
        i18n,
    });

    return {
        props: {
            ...translations,
        },
    };
} catch (error) {
    console.log("TemplateId: ", error);
}
}

export default TemplateId;
```

Comment: The problem is not in the path to the page, it's most likely an issue with a `Link`'s `href` you have in that page. Can you provide the code for the `customize/collection/[colName]/schema/[schemaName]/template/[templateId]/index.tsx` page?

Comment: My code is very simple @juliomalves

Comment: What's the `Container` component? Can you show the code for that as well? Also, do you have any links that link to that template page in your app?

Comment: I removed all source code, just keep skeleton, But it does not work @juliomalves, I think it is not from the code

Comment: Could you provide a [mre], or a repo where the issue is reproducible?